# How to save a function reference as the value in a Map type, and invoke it with a parameter later on in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
val specials:Map<String, (Any)->Unit> = mapOf(
        "callMe1" to {asParam1()}, 
        "callMe2" to {asParam2()}
)

fun asParam1(num:Int) {
    println(num)
}

fun asParam2(text:String) {
    println(text)
}

fun caller() {
    specials["callMe1"]?.invoke("print me")
    specials["callMe2"]?.invoke(123)
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    caller()
}
```

My requirement is simple, I want to save the function `asParam1` and `asParam2` as a value in the variable `specials`. And invoke it later on by fetching the value from a `Map`.

However, the compiler doesn't like it:

> Error:(1, 40) Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred
>   type is Map Unit> but Map Unit> was
>   expected 
>   Error:(1, 69) No value passed for parameter num 
>   Error:(1, 96) No value passed for parameter text

While this task is pretty simple in a weak typed language, I don't know how to do in Kotlin. Any help would be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Using `when` is also ok, if your `Map` is unchanged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct syntax is `"calllme" to ::asParam1`.

But then the signatures will be wrong because the `Map` expects type `(Any)->Unit` and yours have `(Int)->Unit` and `(String)->Unit`. Here is an example that does not produce the error:

```
val specials:Map<String, (Any)->Unit> = mapOf(
        "callMe1" to ::asParam1,
        "callMe2" to ::asParam2
)

fun asParam1(num:Any) {
    if(num is Int) println(num)
}

fun asParam2(text:Any) {
    if(text is String) println(text)
}

fun caller() {
    specials["callMe2"]?.invoke("print me")
    specials["callMe1"]?.invoke(123)
}
```

Keep in mind, your code for the caller has special knowledge about how to call each of your functions (i.e., the correct parameter types), but the compiler does not have this same knowledge.  You could accidentally call `asParam1` passing a `String` instead of an `Int` (which is what your `caller` function was doing, I fixed it in my example) and that is not allowed.  Which is why I changed the signatures of both `asParam*` to accept `Any` parameter, and then validated the expected type in each function (ignoring bad types).

If your intent **is** to pass integers in addition to strings to `asParam2()`, then change the body to test for both `Int` and `String` and convert the integer to a string.

Comment: further note:  if `asParam*()` were methods of a class, the syntax would change a little, you would write `this::asParam1` instead of `::asParam1`

Comment: Thanks for the note, all works now. Yes, the real case is in a class :)

Answer (score 3):

When you write `{ asParam1() }`, you create a lambda with an executable code block inside it, so you need to properly call the function `asParam1(...)`, which requires an `Int` argument.

So, the first change you need to make is: `{ i -> asParam1(i) }`.

But this code will still not pass the type checking, because, matching the type of the map, the lambda will be typed as `(Any) -> Unit` (the values in the map should all be able to accept `Any`, and a function that expects a narrower type cannot be a value in this map).

You then need to convert the `Any` argument to `Int` to be able to invoke the function: 
`{ i -> asParam1(i as Int) }`

Finally, the map will look like this:

```
val specials: Map<String, (Any) -> Unit> = mapOf(
    "callMe1" to { i -> asParam1(i as Int) },
    "callMe2" to { s -> asParam2(s as String) }
)
```

The invocation stays unchanged, as in your code sample.

The function reference syntax (`::asParam1`) would allow you to reference a function that already accepts `Any`, it would not implicitly make the conversion described above. To use it, you would have to modify your functions to accept `Any`, as in [@Les's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45482035/2196460).