# How to map string to function and call it later

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I'm new to Kotlin and what I'm trying to achieve is very simple in dynamically typed languages like Python and JavaScript, but no so easy in Kotlin. I have a set of message handler functions accepting message objects. Each message class implements `Message` interface. I want to map each message handler function to a `String` key:

```
interface Message

data class TestMessage1(val body: String): Message
data class TestMessage2(val body: String): Message

fun testMessage1Handler(msg: TestMessage1) { println(msg.body) }
fun testMessage2Handler(msg: TestMessage2) { println(msg.body) }

val functions = mapOf<String, (Message)->Unit> (
        "testMessage1" to ::testMessage1Handler,
        "testMessage2" to ::testMessage2Handler
)
```

This code gives me two errros:

```
error: type inference failed.
Expected type mismatch: inferred type is
Pair<String, KFunction1<@ParameterName Line_1.TestMessage1, Unit>>
but
Pair<String, (Line_1.Message) -> Unit> was expected

error: type inference failed.
Expected type mismatch: inferred type is 
Pair<String, KFunction1<@ParameterName Line_1.TestMessage2, Unit>>
but
Pair<String, (Line_1.Message) -> Unit> was expected
```

Why can't I use interface `Message` as function type parameter? Since both `TestMessage1` and `TestMessage2` implement this interface it seems correct to me. How would you implement something like this?

There is a related question [How to save a function reference as the value in a Map type, and invoke it with a parameter later on in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481449/how-to-save-a-function-reference-as-the-value-in-a-map-type-and-invoke-it-with) but I don't want to change message handler parameter `msg` type to `Any`

Comment: *Why can't I use interface Message as function type parameter*: because if you try to call testMessage1Handler with a Message as argument, that won't compile: testMessage1Handler is only accepting instances of TestMessage1, not any instance of Message. You would firt need to check if the Message is an instance of TestMessage1 and cast it. And if it's not a TestMessage1, then what?

Comment: Also worth pointing out that while you _can_ refer to functions by name, it's not good practice in a statically-typed language, and almost never needed.  (For one thing, it defeats some automatic refactorings.)  Perhaps if you explain what you're ultimately trying to achieve, someone can suggest a better approach?

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at in another way.

What if instead of trying and failing to specify the type, we give Kotlin chance to infer it, by specifying incorrect type:

```
val functions: String = mapOf(
    "testMessage1" to ::testMessage1Handler,
    "testMessage2" to ::testMessage2Handler
)
```

This produces:

```
inferred type is Map<String, KFunction1<*, Unit>> but String was expected.
```

Now if you put that signature, it will actually compile:

```
val functions = mapOf<String, KFunction1<*, Unit>>(
    "testMessage1" to ::testMessage1Handler,
    "testMessage2" to ::testMessage2Handler
)
```

This is similar to:

```
val functions: Map<String, KFunction1<*, Unit>> = mapOf(
    "testMessage1" to ::testMessage1Handler,
    "testMessage2" to ::testMessage2Handler
)
```

When trying to invoke this, though, you get a hint why this is not correct:

```
functions["testMessage1"]?.invoke(TestMessage1("a"))
```

Gets you

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Nothing
Found: TestMessage1
```

Notice that Kotlin infers that type of your input is `Nothing`

To understand why, let's look at only one function:

```
fun testMessage1Handler(msg: TestMessage1)
```

And ask ourselves: what other type besides `TestMessage1` this function may receive? No other type. It cannot receive TestMessage2. It cannot receive `Message`, since `Message` is not necessarily `TestMessage1`.

For second function, we'll get the same answer. So, the common type of both is `Nothing`. Which makes this abstraction not very useful to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

The following code compiles but renders the question kind of moot.

The type parameters match now. Maybe generics could be applied as well, but I don’t know how.

```
interface Message {
    val body: String
}

data class TestMessage1(override val body: String): Message
data class TestMessage2(override val body: String): Message

fun messageHandler(msg: Message) { println(msg.body) }

val functions = mapOf<String, (Message)->Unit> (
        "testMessage1" to ::messageHandler,
        "testMessage2" to ::messageHandler
)
```